# Store queued events in default connection (leemason/tenantable)

Tags: laravel, events, queue, multi-tenant, jobs

I'm trying to store the queued events in the main connection (jobs table) while I'm in the tenant-connection. I've tried purging the tenant, so the main connection is established. However an error is triggered that the jobs table doesn't exist in the tenant database.

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '<tenant_database>.jobs' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into 'jobs' ('queue', 'payload'....
```

Can anyone help me fixing this issue?

Comment: Check back documentation. You need to run a command to generate job table

Comment: I did, the jobs-table is present in the main-connection where my tenants are stored. However, I want tenant-events queued in this main-connection queue, so: before creating the event, I purge the tenant-connection. But somehow, it keeps the tenant-connection and raises the error that the jobs-table isn't found.

Comment: sorry for late reply. do you get other errors or log. because the error mentioned above is about the jobs table

Comment: Somehow its working now, maybe some minor update fixed the problem. I can't find out what fixed it.